# PHP- Insert all table values to DB in a single click and edit value?

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

how to insert all table values into the database with a single submit button?

how to edit the tables values and update to the database?

for the following code snippet

in the code i want to insert into a  database and display in another table with edit option.

the question is how to update the values to the already exsting values in the database with a **single submit button**.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">SI. No</th>
                <th width="45%">Items / Products</th>
                <th width="5%">Qty Requested</th>
                <th width="20%">Quantity Procured</th>
                <th width="10%">Specification</th>
                <th width="20%">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- row will be dynamically add here 

            <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-0">
                <input type="text" name="sno" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="mail" name="items"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" name="qty_r"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>

            <td class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" name="qty_p" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="mail" name="specification"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" name="phone"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>

            <td class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        -->
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<div class="form-group text-center">
        <label></label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Save <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></button>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sno' + counter + '" value="'+counter+'" /></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="items' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty_r' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty_p' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="specification' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });



    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
        counter -= 1
    });


});


</script>
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no such thing as 'pass an image' in PHP. What you can do is upload it on one page, redirect, and show it on another page. What exactly do you mean with 'pass an image'?

Comment: I think he just wanted to pass the form value (In that case, uploaded image name) via post method to another file. If so then my given example will help him. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check it out. It works for me.
I just added a name attribute in the input type and pass it via post method and don't forget to rename index.html to index.php

***Single Upload Only:***

**index.php**

```
 <form method="POST" action="img.php">
        <img id="img" alt="image" width="100" height="100" />
    <input type="file" name="img_url" onchange="document.getElementById('img').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
    <input type="submit" name="">
```

**img.php**

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['img_url'];

?>
```

***Multiple Uplaod:***

**index.php**

```
<form id="dynamicForm" method="POST" action="img.php">
    <b>This single img works but not in js</b> <br>
    <img id="img" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />
    <input type="file" name="single_img" onchange="document.getElementById('img').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">

    <br/>
    No of Img <input type="text" id="noi" value="" onkeyup="addFields()">
        <br />

     <div id="dynamicField"></div>
<input type="submit" name="">

<script> 


    function addFields(){
        // Number of inputs to create
        var number = document.getElementById("noi").value;
        // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
        var container = document.getElementById("dynamicField");
        var array = ["CRICTICAL","HIGH","LOW","INFO"];
        // Clear previous contents of the container
        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }


        for (i=1;i<=number;i++){

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.width="100";
            img.height="100";
            img.id="img "+i;

            var upload = document.createElement("input");
            upload.type="file";
            upload.name="file_"+i;
            upload.id="upload "+i;
            //Working_______________
            upload.onchange=upload.onchange= function () {

                var img_id=this.getAttribute('id');
                var imgId = img_id.charAt(7) ; 
                document.getElementById("img "+imgId).src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])
            }

            //________________________________________
            container.appendChild(img);
            container.appendChild(upload);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    } 
</script>
```

**img.php**

```
<?php 

$result =  $_POST;
$mul =  count($result);
if($mul>0){
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what to do if the **index.php**  has more than one image?

Comment: If images exist outside of the form then it will not affect anymore And if your from supports more than one image in a single input type, in that case, you might get an array value (not sure). 
Or you use multiple input type then just use the multiple attribute as name like the above.
However, Can you please share the code snippet?

Comment: To get dynamic image fields and pass it to next page chk here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59101028/12113772

Comment: Updated the code snippet  as per your requirements. Hope you will enjoy :)

Comment: well i'll check it out

Comment: unfortunately can't display a image.like this echo $value."<br> <img src=$value>"

Comment: You have to put the uploadable images in the root directory since it is a static site. There is not database and upload directory where images have been stored.
See screenshots_ 1. https://prnt.sc/q3vb66  2. https://prnt.sc/q3vdb2  3. https://prnt.sc/q3vbqc

Comment: another help, is there is any site for Leaderboards and Highscore based on submitting values if the submitted key is correct then adds up the score and display it in the site.

Comment: I would be happier if I could help you but it seems that I heard this for the first time. But I will try to know regarding the topic and let you inform if get any authentic resources.

Comment: actually , i would like create a  CTF with the scoreboard. any idea?